# How do I make the Right Alt+Shift switch languages in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

For long time I've been using the Right Alt+Shift to switch between languages in Windows.
But in Linux it uses the left one. Is there a way to make language switching by the right one?

Comment: Mention your desktop environment: is this standard Ubuntu with Gnome Shell? You can tell DE with command `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many keyboard layouts use <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> (aka <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) by default for accessing 3rd and 4th level symbols. Hence, in order to make the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut work for switching input languages, you need to explicitly select some other 3rd level key.

You may want to edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and consider this line to achieve what you want:

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_alt,lv3:lalt_switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

(You need root access to edit `/etc/default/keyboard`. This is one way to do it:

```
gedit admin:///etc/default/keyboard
```

Then save and reboot.)

That combo turns <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> into the 3rd level key while <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> works for switching languages.

(copied from [this SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/595500))

Comment: this file is read only

Comment: @AhmadAdel: No it's not. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you Mr Gunnar  will help alot of new linux users But I want to draw your attention to something important in ubuntu it will be **XKBOPTIONS=lv3:ralt_alt,lv3:lalt_switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle** without Double quotes but in manjaro you have to use Double quotes

Comment: @AhmadAdel: Ubuntu understands it with or without double quotes. Don't know about Manjaro.